# Couldnt use flutterfire in my flutter project directory, already activated the dart pub flutterfire cli

Tags: flutter, firebase

[So I installed firebase cli, but I couldnt find how to open my flutter app directory with that so that I could configure my project so I opened new cmd in my flutter app directory but cant use the flutterfire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsogj.png)